# How to get width and height of an image loaded from a server in iOS?

Tags: ios

How can I get the width and height of an image which was loaded from a server in iOS? I know with `NSData` we can retrieve the width and height, but it's very slow. Is there any other solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your image is in a `UIImage`, you can use:

```
float width = yourImage.size.width;
float height = yourImage.size.height;
```

FYI, you can pull an image into a `UIImage` from `NSData` using:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:yourData];
```

Answer (score 0):

try with ImageIO framework

> @import ImageIO; ...
>
> NSURL *imageURL = yourUrl
>
> CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, NULL);
>
> NSDictionary* imageProperty = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*)
>
> CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imgSource, 0, NULL);
>
> NSLog(@"%@", imageProperty);
>
> CFRelease(imgSource);